# passing input value in getJSON jquery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, json

i have an `<input>` box that requires user to enter their `ID` number. upon entering i want to print the associated name  of that `ID` from mysql via JSON.

my question is, how do i pass the `ID` value in javascript/jquery

```
$('input#name-submit').on('click', function () { //get the ID input
    var id = $('input#name').val(); // store it in this string

     $.getJSON("fetch.php", {id: id}, function(data) { //pass the ID in fetch.php
        $.each(data.member, function(key, value) { 
            $("#print").text(data.emp[key]["name"]);

        });
    });
```

my fetch.php (not the actual, but this is how i thought it goes)

```
if (isset['id'] == true {
    require 'db.php';

$query = "select * from `members` where `member_no` = '[id]'";
$result = $db->($query);

$myArray = array();
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) 
       array_push($myArray, array('name' => $row [1]);

echo json_encode(array("result" => $myArray));
}
```

the missing piece im looking are

- how to pass the `id` value to my fetch.php via javascript and query the associated name for that ID
- correct logic syntax of my `fetch.php` to display the query into a JSON format, fetch the result and display it on `$("#print")` div.

Comment: it should work... check your browsers network tab to inspect the request sent

Comment: also make sure that the element `$('input#name')` exists.. also remove the `input`.. to `$('#name').val()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Replace**

```
if (isset['id'] == true {
```

**with**

```
if (isset($_GET['id'])) {
     -----^^^^^^^^^^^^---
```

**OR**

```
if (isset($_REQUEST['id'])) {
     -----^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^---
```

You are using `if (isset['id'] == true {` which is wrong if condition to check if passed value `isset` or not you need to use `superglobal` i.e `$_GET,$_POST,$_REQUEST`

Same for MySQL query you are using `['id']` which behave as normal string instead you must use supergloabal as described above.

```
$query = "select * from `members` where `member_no` = '".$_REQUEST['id']."'";
```

**OR**

```
$query = "select * from `members` where `member_no` = '".$_GET['id']."'";
```